# java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message) When new project created in kotlin and i try to run This error Getting .Why i didn't know wts Wrong

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

```
* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException.getMessage(ModuleVersionResolveException.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.exceptions.DefaultMultiCauseException.printStackTrace(DefaultMultiCauseException.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.exceptions.DefaultMultiCauseException.printMultiCauseStackTrace(DefaultMultiCauseException.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.exceptions.DefaultMultiCauseException.printStackTrace(DefaultMultiCauseException.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.exceptions.DefaultMultiCauseException.printSingleCauseStackTrace(DefaultMultiCauseException.java:143)
    at org.gradle.internal.exceptions.DefaultMultiCauseException.printStackTrace(DefaultMultiCauseException.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.event.types.DefaultFailure.fromThrowable(DefaultFailure.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.TaskOperationMapper.toTaskResult(TaskOperationMapper.java:134)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.TaskOperationMapper.createFinishedEvent(TaskOperationMapper.java:113)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.TaskOperationMapper.createFinishedEvent(TaskOperationMapper.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientBuildEventGenerator$EnabledOperation.generateFinishEvent(ClientBuildEventGenerator.java:154)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientBuildEventGenerator.finished(ClientBuildEventGenerator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationListenerManager$ProgressShieldingBuildOperationListener.finished(DefaultBuildOperationListenerManager.java:127)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationListenerManager$1.finished(DefaultBuildOperationListenerManager.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ListenerAdapter.stop(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:214)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$BuildOperationTrackingListener.stop(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:243)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYycu.png)

When i created new Kotlin Project Its getting like this .....i did written any any code or ui design or gredle dependencies .projected created and i run.This error gettion

Answer (score 0):

Sync the project with gradle and rebuild your project

Comment: I tried all Possibilites..